# Can we use Qlikview chart in our html page?

Tags: html, qlikview

I am new to qlikview . I want to know whether can we able to use qlikview chart into html pages?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not using the personal edition version then your software should have come with Qlikview Publisher. This would allow you to set up an HTML AccessPoint where your users would be able to access the dashboard. Your content would be displayed using a few different plugins such as IE or AJAC Zero Footprint.